# Make JAXB XJC generate a wrapping class for a simple type

Tags: java, jaxb, xjc

I have the following xml types:

```
<xsd:element name="FaxNumbers" minOccurs="0">
    <xsd:complexType>
        <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element name="FaxNumber" type="FaxNumber" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
        </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>
</xsd:element>
```

The FaxNumber type looks like this:

```
<xsd:simpleType name="FaxNumber">
    <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
        <xsd:minLength value="1" />
    </xsd:restriction>
</xsd:simpleType>
```

The resulting xml should be something like this:

```
<FaxNumbers>
    <FaxNumber>3878374</FaxNumber>
    <FaxNumber>387833434</FaxNumber>
    <FaxNumber>3878334</FaxNumber>
</FaxNumbers>
```

When running JAXB XJC to generate java classes from XSD it generates the following class:

```
@XmlType(name = "FaxNumbers")
public class FaxNumbers  {

    /**
     * No comment.
     */
    @XmlElement(name = "FaxNumber", required = true)
    protected List<String> faxNumber = new ArrayList<String>();

}
```

However i would like bind **FaxNumber** to composite class like this:

```
@XmlType(name = "FaxNumbers")
public class FaxNumbers  {

    /**
     * No comment.
     */
    @XmlElement(name = "FaxNumber", required = true)
    protected List<FaxNumber> faxNumber = new ArrayList<String>();

}

Where FaxNumber class looks like this:

public class FaxNumber{

    @XmlValue
    private String value;
}
```

Is there a way to define such binding in JAXB bindings xml?

Note: Unfortunately I don't have control over and cannot change the XSD

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't think you can get xjc to generate such a FaxNumber class for you, but you can write it yourself and then use an external binding file to slot it in at the right place.

```
package com.example;
public class FaxNumber {
  private String value;
  // getter/setter

  public static FaxNumber parse(String s) {
    FaxNumber n = new FaxNumber();
    n.value = s;
    return n;
  }

  public static String print(FaxNumber n) {
    return n.value;
  }
}
```

Bindings:

```
<jaxb:bindings xmlns:jaxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb"
           xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
           jaxb:version="2.0">
  <jaxb:bindings schemaLocation="example.xsd">
    <jaxb:bindings node="//xsd:simpleType[@name='FaxNumber']">
      <jaxb:javaType name="com.example.FaxNumber"
          parseMethod="com.example.FaxNumber.parse"
          printMethod="com.example.FaxNumber.print"/>
    </jaxb:bindings>
  </jaxb:bindings>
<jaxb:bindings>
```

Answer (score 1):

instead of line `<xsd:element name="FaxNumber" type="FaxNumber" maxOccurs="unbounded" />` in your FaxNumbers xsd definition use `<xsd:element name="FaxNumber" ref="FaxNumber" maxOccurs="unbounded" />`. I think this is your problem

Comment: Unfortunately I don't control and cannot change the XSD (will update the original post).

Comment: then I am afraid you are stuck with manual modification of generated java file before you use it. If it is possible for your case

Comment: Manual editing the generated java files works fine. However when the XSD is changed and I pre-generate the files I have to do the update manually every time.

Comment: I am confused. It is possible that somebody else changes the xsd, but you cannot?

Comment: They're controlled by external authority that my application has to communicate with.

Comment: this is probably not very helpful, but I have to say it, I would propose to contact this external authority saying they've provided you with not suitable xsd:)

Answer (score 1):

Following works for me. Hope that helps!

**XSD**:

```
 <xsd:schema xmlns="http://www.hcentive.com/ws/eligibility/schema/beans"
    targetNamespace="http://www.hcentive.com/ws/eligibility/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<xsd:element name="FaxNumbers">
    <xsd:complexType>
        <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element name="FaxNumber" type="FaxNumber" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
        </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>
</xsd:element>
<xsd:complexType name="FaxNumber">
    <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element type="xsd:string" name="value" />
    </xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>
</xsd:schema>
```

**Generated object: FaxNumbers.java**

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "", propOrder = {
    "faxNumber"
})
@XmlRootElement(name = "FaxNumbers")
public class FaxNumbers {

    @XmlElement(name = "FaxNumber", required = true)
    protected List<FaxNumber> faxNumber;

    /**
     * Gets the value of the faxNumber property.
     * 
     * <p>
     * This accessor method returns a reference to the live list,
     * not a snapshot. Therefore any modification you make to the
     * returned list will be present inside the JAXB object.
     * This is why there is not a <CODE>set</CODE> method for the faxNumber property.
     * 
     * <p>
     * For example, to add a new item, do as follows:
     * <pre>
     *    getFaxNumber().add(newItem);
     * </pre>
     * 
     * 
     * <p>
     * Objects of the following type(s) are allowed in the list
     * {@link FaxNumber }
     * 
     * 
     */
    public List<FaxNumber> getFaxNumber() {
        if (faxNumber == null) {
            faxNumber = new ArrayList<FaxNumber>();
        }
        return this.faxNumber;
    }

}
```

Comment: As I posted in the question, I cannot modify the XSD.

Comment: Then what can you modify? You are generating Java classes only from XSD right?

Comment: That's exactly what I'm doing.

Comment: But in this case there is no generated class for "FaxNumber", right? This is analogous to the problem I am having.

Comment: Ah, disregard my comment -- I didn't realize xjc was actually generating a separate file for this type.